# Getting values of json array in Mocha JS

Tags: javascript, json, mocha.js

I have following issue, this json is returned by api:

```js
"products": {
  "10432471": {
     "id": 10432471
  },
  "10432481": {
     "id": 10432481
  }
}
```

and I need to get names of all variables under `products` array, how to get them?
That values are constantly changing everyday, so I can not refer to their names

Trying `console.log(res.body.menu.categories[i].products.values());` but its not worked.

Any sugesstion how can I get `10432471` and `10432481` from products? Without referring to variable names.

Comment: 10432471 and 10432481 are available in two spots: the value of the id and the keys under products. Will these always be the same?

Comment: yes, these values will be always the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to get that via `Object.keys(res.body.menu.categories[i].products)`

Comment: Ok, worked for me, thanks. And by the way, how to save these numbers to array as separated value?

Comment: You could also do `var array = Object.keys(res.body.menu.categories[i].products) // "10432471", "10432481"]`

Answer (score 0):

To get the object properties, the shortest is using [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
var obj = {"products": {
    "10432471": {
       "id": 10432471
    },
    "10432481": {
       "id": 10432481
    }
  }}

var properties = Object.keys(obj.products)

console.log(properties)
```

Comment: Ok, worked for me, thanks. And by the way, how to save these numbers to array as separated value?

Comment: @user10248787 properties is an array. if you want you could do `var value1 = properties[0]:`